# Finding a file's path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, path

I am developing an C# Visual Studio application and I am using a config.txt file. But when the application is installed on another machine, how can I find the config.txt file path, taking into consideration that the user will install the application on a custom path (C:\Folder X) ?

Comment: This will depend upon how are you installing the application. Please provide more inputs on how are you installing application.

Comment: Everybody is assuming that the file will be with the Executable, where as OP didn't mention anything about it.

Comment: The application is packed in a msi, and the file is unpacked together with the other files including the exe file in the path given by the user in the msi wizard. I need the path of this file to read the configurations when the application is executed. the file content can be modified in order to change the configuration of the application.

Comment: In that case any of the following answer will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the config file is on the same directory that the executable, you could use:

```
string exePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string configFileName = "config.txt";

string configFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath), configFileName);
```

---

EDIT:

The `GetExecutingAssembly()` should have returned the path `C:\Program Files\MyAddIn\your_plugin.dll`, as it returns the actual path of the loaded assembly that calls it.

As it's not the case, we could guess MS Project is actually copying your dll into a local (and maybe temporary) directory before loading it (the `....\AppData\Local\Assembly\...` path).

As I don't know *why* and *how* MS Project does this, the safest way to deal with your problem I think is to store the location of your Addin folder into the registry on installation. If you're shipping it as an MSI, it should be easy to make your installer adds a registry key that contains your plugin file location. How to do this will depend on how you build your MSI: vdproj? WiX?.

Then in the code of your plugin, you could read into registry to get your path.

Comment: This gives me the following path: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Assembly\dl3....\config.txt. But the file is: C:\Program Files\Application\config.txt

Comment: @yozcia Looks like you call the code from an assembly located in another location than the executable itself. Try to replace `GetExecutingAssembly` by `GetEntryAssembly`

Comment: this gives me null error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. My application is an add-on  for MS PROJECT. What it does is to read the config file every time I open MS PROJECT. The problem is that, when I install the application on a different path, I can't find the path anymore.

Comment: @yozcia You didn't mentioned you were coding an add-on to an existing application. `GetExecutingAssembly()` returns null as the executable file is not yours but MS Project. Where is your config.txt file located? MS project directory? Plugin directory? User directory?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me out. The add-on is packed in an msi, and when the user is installing the msi, he chooses a path, let's say C:\Program Files\MyAddIn, and the path for the config file will be C:\Program Files\MyAddIn\config.txt. Now, after the installation, when MS Project is opened, it reads the config file, and I need to find the path of this config file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a text file you could use the .net settings to store the settings for this app.

More info can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the config file is in the same folder as the application you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`